# Are there phi2 phi3 statistics for the DF-GLS unit root test?

Tags: time-series, augmented-dickey-fuller

It's known that there are phi 2 and phi 3 statistics when performing ADF unit root tests. These statistics tell us the correct specification of the model (Trend, constant, or none). When running ADF on R, it's common to see phi 2 and phi 3 in the output. Now that I'm running DF-GLS they simply aren't in the output, and I don't know if it's simply not possible to use these statistics for DF-GLS or, if being possible, how to perform them. If not possible to get these statistics, what's the best way for choosing the correct specification for DF-GLS? I have many variables that show different results for the different specifications, and I just don't know what to do about it.